# UICollectionView content hidden by TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift5, uitabbar

### The problem

Hello, community! I created a UICollectionView programmatically and want it to display images that take the full size of the screen, surpassing the top safe area but respecting the bottom safe area, since at the bottom I have TabBar. The issue with the current UI is that I got it to ignore the top safe area, but the tab bar hides part of the content since the collection takes the size of the whole screen ([Video](https://youtu.be/-12K9kNPLmc)). I'm trying so that my UI looks like the TikTok home page where the collectionView ends when the tab bar starts.

### My Code

**In ViewDidLoad:**

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.bottom
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView?.register(PostCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PostCollectionViewCell.identifier)
collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
collectionView?.dataSource = self
collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
view.addSubview(collectionView!)
```

**In ViewDidLayoutSubviews:**

```
collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
collectionView?.frame = view.bounds
```

### What I've tried

```
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)!)
```

*Substracting height of tabBar to CollectionViewFlowLayout*

```
collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height, right: 0)
collectionView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height)
```

**Many Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use auto-layout instead of setting the frame of your collection view manually. After `view.addSubview(collectionView!)` put:

```
collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

This pins the bottom anchor of the collection viewto the bottom safe area of your view, which should account for the tab bar.

You should remove `collectionView?.frame = view.bounds` from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Also you should not set your `itemSize` in `viewDidLoad` because the view's frame may change. You can set it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.